# Vertical align a child div to the bottom of a parent div, and set the child as a percentage of the parent's height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertical align a child div to the bottom of its parent div, and set it as a percentage of the parent's height.

However, the height: 20% property of the child seems to be getting ignored, and the div stretches to take up the entire 100%.

The end goal is to have a full-screen title page photo as an intro to an article, with a semi-opaque bar running along the bottom of the photo that will have the title of the article in it. I'm using percentages to make it a responsive design for any size screen.

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/A52fw/1/

**HTML:**

```
<body>
   <div id="outerdiv">
      <div id="innerdiv">
      test
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#outerdiv {
height: 100%;
width: 100%; 
display: table;
}       

#innerdiv {
width: 100%; 
height: 20%;
background-color: red;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use positioning (relative on the parent, absolute on the child) instead of the display property:

```
#outerdiv {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
}
#innerdiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: red;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/A52fw/2/)**

Comment: `#innerdiv`'s position could also be made `relative` with `top:80%` set.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without absolute positioning, since you know the height of the child.

```
#outerdiv {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
    display: table;
} 

#innerdiv {
   width: 100%; 
   height: 20%;
   margin-top: 80%;
}
```

In case your height is in pixels you can use:

```
#innerdiv {
   width: 100%; 
   height: 40px;
   margin-top: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

Comment: `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` are unfortunately relative to the with instead of the height, so this will not work.